# Fatal Error register_globals is disabled

Tags: php, .htaccess, error-handling

i am having this error on localhost

> FATAL ERROR: register_globals is disabled in php.ini, please enable
>   it!

i have added **php.ini** file with

```
<?php 
register_globals=1;
?>
```

when i was working on live site i hade the same problem which was solved by adding the above statement in the php.ini file but doing the same thing on localhost its still giving me this error. 
 i have also changed the .htaccess file but still no success .

Comment: That isn't a php.ini file format in your post. Also, [This feature has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php).

Comment: If you really must do this on an older site (pre-PHP 5.4), and it's highly discouraged -- find your php.ini file by putting `phpinfo();` on a php page and look for that entry. The [.htaccess format](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-globals) is `php_flag register_globals off`.

Comment: then how should i solve this error plz help

Comment: when i turn it on "php_flag register_globals on" in the .htaccess file it creates another error 500 for me

Comment: Find what is asking you turn it on and update that software?

Comment: sorry i dont understand what u r saying

Answer (score 0):

I have Found the solution if someone is looking for the answer to the same error here is the answer:

first of all i have uninstalled the xampp server and installed wampp instead and in the ".htaccess" file add these lines

```
<IfModule mod_php4.c>
php_value session.use_trans_sid 0
php_value register_globals 1
</IfModule>
```

by doing so your site will work perfectly fine .. cheers :)